# Creating a ReactiveUI derived collection with more elements than the original

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Is it possible to create a ReactiveUI derived collection that has more elements in it than the original?

I've seen that there is a way of filtering a collection, and selecting single properties, but what I'm looking for is the equivalent of the SelectMany operation for enumerables.

To illustrate, imagine trying to get a derived collection representing every passenger stuck in a traffic jam.

```
class Car 
{
    ReactiveCollection<Passenger> Passengers;
}

var TrafficJam=new ReactiveCollection<Car>();
EveryPassengerInTheTrafficJam=Cars.CreateDerivedCollection(c=>c.Passengers);
```

The above doesn't work, I think the error was `IEnumerable<ReactiveCollection<Passenger>>` can't be cast to `ReactiveCollection<Passenger>` - or something up with the types, in any case.

I can't figure out the right approach for this flattening - admittedly I may be barking up completely the wrong tree here, so please let me know if there's a better way of achieving the same thing!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the moment, `CreateDerivedCollection` doesn't support `SelectMany` as a transformation, it gets too Tricky to handle removes. If you don't have many items, you can just regenerate the collection every time:

```
cars.Changed
    .Select(_ => cars.SelectMany(x => x.Passengers).ToList())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Passengers);
```

**Edit:** Alright, here we go:

```
var whenCarsOrPassengersInThoseCarsChange = Observable.Merge(
    cars.Changed
        .SelectMany(_ =>
            cars.Select(x => x.Passengers.Changed).Merge())
        .Select(_ => Unit.Default),
    cars.Changed.Select(_ => Unit.Default));

whenCarsOrPassengersInThoseCarsChange.StartWith(Unit.Default)
    .Select(_ => cars.SelectMany(x => x.Passengers).ToList())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Passengers);
```

So, the idea is that we've got two main situations when we want to reevaluate the passengers list:

1. When one of the passengers change in the cars
2. When one of the cars change

However, the tricky part is, *we only want to watch passengers for cars in the collection* (i.e. if a car is removed, we no longer care about its passengers).

#### Properly tracking suicidal passengers

So, the idea in that weird SelectMany is, "Every time the car list changes, build a new list of Observables that represent when the passenger collection changes, and merge them all together".

However, if we *only* had that statement, we would have to wait for a car to be added *and* its passengers change before we got a new passenger list, so we also have to update when the list of cars change too.

#### What's this "Unit" business?

In this case, I actually don't care about the values that these Observables put out, just when they happen. "Unit" is the Rx version of void, it only has a single value, "Unit.Default". You use it when you only care when something happens, not what the value of it is.

Comment: One side effect of this question is now I gotta go learn how your framework works. :)

Comment: So, the reason that the straightforward version doesn't work, is that the `cars.SelectMany` returns an `IEnumerable` (a `SelectManyEnumerable` or something), not a type like `ObservableCollection`. There is no way for `CreateDerivedCollection` to figure out how to watch this collection, so it will populate initially but not update as `cars` has items added / removed

Comment: @PaulBetts Ideally, I'd like to recalculate when a passenger collection in a car changes (someone gets out in desperation, Everybody Hurts style), or when the car collection changes (a new car arrives in the traffic jam), but **not** on other properties of the car (if WindscreenWipersEnabled becomes true, I don't want to recompute EveryPassengerInTheTrafficJam!). Is this possible?

Comment: @JerKimball definitely! I'm a complete ReactiveUI (and reactive programming) newbie, but from what I've seen so far, it is **very** cool. I love how it makes it possible to describe the whole behaviour of a user interface in a declarative way.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Paul's code requires to wait if the passengers of a car change before the cars do. I updated it to add `StartWith(Unit.Default)` before selecting the `Passengers.Changed` observables and it works.

Comment: @PaulBetts so I've used this technique in an app of mine to good effect. But now another question ... how do I track changes on the Passengers? :-)

Simple example, say the list of Passengers is bound to a list on the UI. And the Passenger has an IsSelected bool property that is bound to the Selected property of the item in the list. Can I get a derived collection of the selected passengers? Basically, I want to know when the number of selected passengers changes so that a command is only available when there is at least one selected. This one has me stumped so far.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...I'm not all that familiar with ReactiveUI, but just reading thru, it looks like you need to alter where your `SelectMany` goes:

```
var jam = cars.SelectMany(x => x.Passengers).CreateDerivedCollection(p => p);
```