# ReactiveUI SelectMany form of CreateDerivedCollection

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Using ReactiveUI 6.5, I'm trying achieve something like a SelectMany LINQ expression with the CreateDerivedCollection feature of RxUI. The objects in my source collection (type 'A') have an `IsSelected` property, as well as another collection property where the items are of type 'B'. I want to end up with an `IReactiveDerivedList<B>` which is a flattened list of all of the B objects from the A's that are selected. Hopefully that makes sense.

To make it a little more concrete, let's use an example of an app for browsing log files. Say we have a `LogFileViewModel` type and our main screen's view model has a list of these. Each instance in the list represents a log file on the system, and we present a list of these that the user can select. It's a multi-select list so they can select more than one at a time.

The `LogFileViewModel` then has an `IsSelected` boolean property, which will be set to true/false as the user selects or deselects the corresponding item in the list. And it has a property which is a `List<LogEntry>`. Each `LogEntry` object of course represents one entry in the corresponding log file.

What I want to do then is have a reactive list in the main view model which is a list of all of the `LogEntry` objects for all of the currently selected `LogFileViewModel` objects. The ReactiveList of selected log files is easy, but I'm stuck on the second part. Here's what the main view model would basically look like:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //This gets initialized with the log files somehow, doesn't matter
        LogFiles = new List<LogFileViewModel(...);

        SelectedLogFiles = LogFiles.CreateDerivedCollection(l => l, l => l.IsSelected);
        SelectedLogFileEntries = ? //How to create this one?
    }

    public List<LogFileViewModel> LogFiles { get; private set; }
    public IReactiveDerivedList<LogFileViewModel> SelectedLogFiles { get; private set; }
    public IReactiveDerivedList<LogEntry> SelectedLogFileEntries { get; private set; }
}
```

Is there a known way to do this that I'm just not seeing? If not, any clever ideas to achieve this behavior? :-)

**Edit** :
Looks like I missed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254708/creating-a-reactiveui-derived-collection-with-more-elements-than-the-original) in my initial search. Paul provided the "clever" solution to this problem about 2 years ago. So my question now ... is this still the best way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You can try BLinq or CLinq instead, as they do implement `.SelectMany`

Comment: or even maybe OLinq.

Comment: @Aron. Thanks, those projects look interesting. Had never seen those before. For now though, I'd like to stay in the realm of Rx and Rx-UI, especially since there seems to be a way to do it (see link I posted in my edit). I'm just wondering now if there's a simpler/cleaner way to do it in the latest version of Rx-UI.